# how to change the style of the header on one page only in prestashop

Tags: css, prestashop

The header style in the checkout page is not in the same as on other pages.And I can not find the template for the checkout page so that I can edit it

Answer (score 0):

Use the inspector in Chrome (DevTools) to inspect the page and you should find a unique ID for the `<body>` tag (possibly `<body id="authentication" class=...`) Then you can target your header in your css like this:

```
body#authentication header {

}
```

Comment: yes I find it in that same form you said and I add my css style but when i refresh the new css does not upload

Comment: try clearing your cache.  your browser will keep using the old css file from cache until it expires unless you clear the cache.  the method for this is different for different browsers.  Google how to do this for your browser.

Comment: thanks a lot it was problem with clone I verified the wrong clone